# pass in table name to sqlalchemy query through url in flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**In short**, how do i

```
 var="TableName"
 models.var.query.all()
```

**explanation**
My goal is to allow the user to change the order of list of items. 
I set up an ajax call that sends an array of id's to the api below.
It works if i hard code the query, and make a api view per table.
my problem is that i want "table" to fill in this line

```
 models.table.query.filter_by(id=item).first()
```

to complete the query.

here is the view api which gives me an error "no attribute 'table'"

```
@app.route('/order/<table>')
def order(table):
    # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    sortedItems = request.args.listvalues()[0]
    o=1
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    for item in sortedItems:
        grab = models.table.query.filter_by(id=item).first() 
        grab.order=o
        o=o+1
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify(result=sortedItems)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
>>> var = 'table_name'
>>> table = getattr(models, var)
>>> table.query.filter_by(id=item).first()
```

`getattr()` will raise an `AttributeError` if the attribute your trying to get does not exist.

Example for your `order()`-function:

```
@app.route('/order/<table>')
def order(table):
    sortedItems = request.args.listvalues()[0]
    o=1
    table = getattr(models, table)
    for item in sortedItems:
        grab = table.query.filter_by(id=item).first() 
        grab.order=o
        o=o+1
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify(result=sortedItems)
```